# I did apt remove mysql-common but instead ended up removing gnome-control-center and ubuntu desktop utilities along side

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, mysql

```
Start-Date: 2021-09-01  20:39:05
Commandline: apt purge mysql-server
Requested-By: user (1000)
Purge: mysql-server:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
End-Date: 2021-09-01  20:39:07

Start-Date: 2021-09-01  20:39:27
Commandline: apt autoremove
Requested-By: user (1000)
Remove: mecab-utils:amd64 (0.996-10build1), libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1), mysql-server-8.0:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), libcgi-fast-perl:amd64 (1:2.15-1), libfcgi-perl:amd64 (0.79-1), libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-10build1), mecab-ipadic-utf8:amd64 (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1), libcgi-pm-perl:amd64 (4.46-1), libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1), libhtml-template-perl:amd64 (2.97-1), mecab-ipadic:amd64 (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1), mysql-server-core-8.0:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2)
End-Date: 2021-09-01  20:39:55

Start-Date: 2021-09-01  20:43:46
Commandline: apt remove mysql-common
Requested-By: user (1000)
Remove: ubuntu-desktop-minimal:amd64 (1.450.2), gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2), printer-driver-hpcups:amd64 (3.20.3+dfsg0-2), sane-utils:amd64 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2), mysql-client-8.0:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), ubuntu-desktop:amd64 (1.450.2), default-mysql-client:amd64 (1.0.5ubuntu2), libsnmp35:amd64 (5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.3), hplip:amd64 (3.20.3+dfsg0-2), libhpmud0:amd64 (3.20.3+dfsg0-2), mysql-common:amd64 (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2), libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), libsane-hpaio:amd64 (3.20.3+dfsg0-2), libsane:amd64 (1.0.29-0ubuntu5.2), colord:amd64 (1.4.4-2)
End-Date: 2021-09-01  20:44:52
```

Why did this happen? As a fool as I am, I read that AND removed it and later panicked. But then i got the logs from apt history and was relieved to find that only extras utilities were removed.
I am new to ubuntu, so I apologise for any ignorance I have regarding this.

Comment: This article describes the removal process : https://www.makeuseof.com/apt-get-uninstall/  this should help answer your question

Comment: Nope. What I wanted to know was why did gnome-control-center got removed when i tried to remove the mysql-common package.

Comment: It got removed because it was installed with the mysql-common package, thus gnome-control-center:amd64 (1:3.36.5-0ubuntu2) got deleted when you removed the mysql-commaon package.  Otherwise it wouldn't have been removed with `apt remove mysql-common`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OP's question I am not sure why the following packages were removed:`apt purge mysql-server` and `apt remove mysql-common`.  I have a recent install of ubuntu 20.04 and there are files on my system related to `mysql` and `mysql-common` even though I never actually installed mysql myself.  This leads me to the conclusion that these are base packages which are probably necessary for at least partial functionality of the overall system.  I am not certain about `mysql-server` but I would definitely NOT recommend removing `mysql-common` unless there is a justifiable reason for doing so.